# jQuery style accordion not expanding all unordered lists

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a menu and I want to create an accordion style menu using jQuery.  The problem i'm having is with the jQuery.

When I click on any of the first `<li>` such as First Menu it expands only up the next `<ul>` and not the nested list within.

How can i edit my jQuery so it expands all the `<ul>` within the parent `<li>`?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">First Menu...</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum/a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Menu...</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum/a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Menu...</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum/a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
        if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
            // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
            $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
            $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

            // open our new menu and add the open class
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }

        else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use default accordin by jquery UI

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/